# Transfer R into C similar language - unknown syntax

Tags: r

At the moment I am trying to figure out some things in R to be able to transfer some pieces of its code into my C++ / C# project.

As an example, I am looking at **diff** function in R :

```
> diff.Date

function (x, lag = 1L, differences = 1L, ...) 
{
    ismat <- is.matrix(x)
    xlen <- if (ismat) 
        dim(x)[1L]
    else length(x)
    if (length(lag) != 1L || length(differences) > 1L || lag < 
        1L || differences < 1L) 
        stop("'lag' and 'differences' must be integers >= 1")
    if (lag * differences >= xlen) 
        return(structure(numeric(), class = "difftime", units = "days"))
    r <- x
    i1 <- -seq_len(lag)
    if (ismat) 
        for (i in seq_len(differences)) r <- r[i1, , drop = FALSE] - 
            r[-nrow(r):-(nrow(r) - lag + 1L), , drop = FALSE]
    else 
        for (i in seq_len(differences)) 
            r <- r[i1] - r[-length(r):-(length(r) - lag + 1L)]
    r
}
```

**Questions** :

- what does minus sign mean before sequence `i1 <- -seq_len(lag)`?
- `?diff` says that sometimes **diff** may be recursive, where is recursion?
- `i1 <- -seq_len(lag)` should create vector, how can it be used as an index here `r[i1]`?
- is there some package that could translate selected function from R into C++?

Comment: `-` before a vector just negates all its values, for example `-(1:3)`. Re your third point, a vector can serve as an index within another vector. What problem are you having with that? For example, `letters[3:6]`. repressiveness means that if `differences` > 1, then `diff` runs `lag` `differences` - 1 times, each time on the result of the previous operation. Your last question is OT on SO.

Comment: @DavidArenburg : so, indexing one vector within another is like getting subset (sample) from general set (population)?

Comment: Re the second question, it doesn't use recursion in terms of calling itself, but it does repeatedly call `r <- r[i1] - r[-length(r):-(length(r) - lag + 1L)]` as many times as specified by `differences`. I think this is what is being referred to.

Comment: *Recursivness (or whatever it should be spelled). And yes, indexing one vector within another is the same as indexing a vector of length one within another- just getting a subset of the same length as the index.

Comment: To answer your last question, no, such a magical package does not exist, you'll have to do the hard work yourself.